# PHP setcookie not working on subfolders

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I've got the following PHP code which sets a cookie called lang to the value of en.

```
setcookie('lang','en',time() + (86400 * 14));
```

This is sometimes set via a script on the root or sometimes inside a subfolder. I'm reading the value of the cookie from subfolders and the root like this:

```
echo $_COOKIE['lang'];
```

Problem i am having is that if i set the cookie from inside a subfolder, i cannot read that value. So a cookie value seems to be created for each subfolder.

Any ideas how i can resolve this? I dont want to have a cookie for each folder for the same cookie name lang

*** UPDATE ***

I've changed to code to make the cookie apply to /. Does this mean that the cookie will apply to all subfolders?

```
setcookie('lang',$selected_language,time() + (86400 * 14),'/');
```

Comment: Seems to be created for each subfolder? Yes, that's exactly what *The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in* means. I suspect you found this code somewhere but didn't really check the docs :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here http://php.net/setcookie that is the default behavior for `setcookie()` function.

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

You should set your path to '/' if you want your cookies to be valid for whole domain.

Comment: Thanks, i've added the / and edited my post with the code including the /. does this / mean it will apply to the entire domain?

Comment: `If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain` I believe it means that if set to '/', it will be available to the entire domain.